# Java - Detect a ping

Tags: java, networking, ping

Is it possible to detect a ping? I.e. device 1 pings device 2 and I want code that can run on device 2 that would detect whenever it is pinged by device 1.

Comment: You need a listener running on a particular port that clients send that ping to using the agreed upon protocol.  You can do it with sockets, HTTP, etc.

Comment: Take a look at this https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-count-number-of-online-users/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *literal* message used by the `ping` utility ("ICMP Echo Request") can be difficult to detect because it is customarily handled, and "eaten," by the network protocol-stack.

But if you simply want one computer or process to "broadcast" the fact that it's present *(i.e.* you don't need to receive a "reply," and you don't strictly care whether the message actually arrives at a particular place), the "UDP" network protocol might be just what you're looking for.  Programming examples abound on the Internet.  (And, right here, awaiting your "search.")

("UDP" is a *datagram* protocol, which so-to-speak "tosses a paper airplane out the window", whereas "TCP/IP" is concerned with bidirectional *connections* that are established, used, then torn-down.)

Answer (score 1):

You can open a TCP or UDP socket on device 2 on some specific port and then try to connect on same port from device 1.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html

You can decide what you want to use by reading about TCP and UDP.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol